# How do I force Angular2 to return JS instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, angular, express, systemjs

I have an express app calling an Angular2 app. I am consistently getting Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token < and searching for a bit has led me to find that this is typically due to the wrong content-type being returned.

I found that app.module.js is returning html and not .js, is this what is throwing the code off?

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
```

The error in detail is:

```
dashboard:21 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:3:20)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:8:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:9:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/main.js
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:3:20)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:8:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:3000/main.js:9:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/main.js
```

Here is a snapshot of it as dev tools for network:
[image]

This is what my express looks like:

```
app.use('/styles.css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/styles.css')));
app.use('/systemjs.config.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/systemjs.config.js')));
app.use('/systemjs-angular-loader.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js')));
app.use('/systemjs.config.extras.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/systemjs.config.extras.js')));
app.use('/main.js.map', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/main.js.map')));

app.use('/main.js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/main.js')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../angular')));
app.use('/api/', auditlog);
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../angular/src/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: It is unlikely `app.module.js` is _returning_ HTML. It is most likely one of two things: either your router isn't routing your request and falls back to sending `index.html` or your API is returning HTML in lieu of JSON.

Comment: Hi Randy I think you're right. Does my express app need to know which routes are to be sent to angular? And is the last line the app.get('*')... bit not enough to direct the query to return the right component from Angular?

Comment: @RandyCasburn instead of JSON**

Comment: @MotassemMK - are we really word smithing now? see: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--lieu--of

Comment: @RustySchmidt - Please share the URL you use and expect to get JSON back from your Express server.

Comment: I'm running a setup similar to this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli The idea is that I have an express app running on the same codebase as an Angular app and when there is no match on the express side, it goes to Angular.

Comment: @RustySchmidt dude, that guide is from 2016. Angular-Cli doesn't use SystemJS anymore, it uses Webpack. If you want to have server-side-rendering, take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/universal or at this: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/seo-angular-part-1-rendertron-meta-tags/ Both tutorials utilize a .ts or .js file that delegates a request either to a server-side-rendered express-site or to the real Angular-hoster. I think that file is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your express app is set up to serve index.html to any request, so you'll get that file back when you might usually get a 404. Given the error, I'm guessing it likely that you have a missing JS file, or possibly some missing SystemJS module mappings. You can use the network inspector to find the missing file by looking in the preview tab of the request.

Consuming all routes is handy for Angular because of its routing, but it might be helpful to check if the client is requesting text/html before returning the app, returning 404 if not - This will make it easier to identify missing JS files on the client side.